# Is it possible to create dashboards and reports that can be distributed as web-based applications?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, software-distribution

**Some background:**

I am working on a capstone project for my university involving greenhouse sensor automation through a Raspberry Pi and Arduino configuration. As well, there is integration for this to work over a MySQL server, where commands and values are passed between the two with the hope of having users control certain values within the greenhouse (Raspberry Pi) system.

With this, I was hoping to use a free report building tool that uses the data from MySQL to display current temperature, humidity, and other statistics in a dashboard view, and then allow users to change how the system reacts to the environment (as well as add more systems to be monitored, how many units it monitors, etc.). Then, I need to be able to have these reports able to be distributed over GitHub, BitBucket, Dropbox etc. so that all the applications we include in our solution can be downloaded over the Internet and used for other users' greenhouse plans.

The idea is that I need to distribute a basic, empty version of the MySQL database with all its tables, procedures and scheduled events, and then the user dashboards/reports that can be viewed over the Internet. Basically, we want to publish the same design of the dashboards and reports to be used with their greenhouse database without other users having to rebuild them.

**My questions:**

Is this technically possible to do, to distribute reports that can be hosted by another user for their own use of our software package? Secondly, what report builder programs could do this? We are looking at free programs, like Birt, currently, and also hope to have a mobile view for these as well.

Comment: How bis is the data ? Why tables or MySQL specific? Can this application query JSON data over the internet ?

Comment: The data is not very large. I'd suspect out of all the tables, there would be less than 1000 rows in total with the largest table having about 500 rows and most others only having a few. I've never worked with JSON before so I didn't think of that (still a student :] ). I chose MySQL because it is free and if someone decides to use our package then they would not have to pay for the server. And I'm not sure what you mean by just the tables. Could you explain what you are looking for so I could answer you more accurately?

Comment: Take a look at Power BI, you can easily distribute the built reports, your users have to set up the connection to the mysql database though.

Comment: I'll take a look at it again. I have rows that produce data every minute and will need to be shown but PowerBI could only read down to a Daily range when I had tried it in the few mins I spared it. If I need to, I can make two extra columns that act as an hour and minute calculator to separate data that way and I will look at Power BI again and give it another go! Thanks!